# Why don't US schools have fixed notification dates for PhD admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

I.e. why don't schools say "we will announce decisions in n rounds: first round date X, second round date Y, etc."?

For the applicants' mental well-being, this seems like a much better option than waiting  for results that might arrive any time. Sure individual faculty members can still reach out to applicants, but I am focusing on official responses.

Since most academic conferences/journals already have such dates, the concept is not unfamiliar. I figured there must be logistical reasons for this absence. What are they?

Alternatively, if schools have such predetermined dates internally, why don't they make them public?

Comment: Why do you believe "applicants' mental well-being" should be a key consideration (beyond basic human decency)? Why is that the school's responsibility? If you make internal deadlines public, people can sue if you don't meet these deadlines for some reason.

Comment: I do like that you provided supporting evidence for the idea that faculty have heard of deadlines lol

Answer (score 6):

Academics are not big on deadlines, and many internal deadlines are soft, anyway.  There are various things that come up sporadically throughout the year (conferences, grant deadlines, faculty interviews, exams, etc) that make certain times busier than others.  Research progress also does not typically run according to a timetable.  As a consequence, there's a general culture of setting rough priorities and targets, but just getting things done when you can.  (By the way, most journals do not have deadlines.)

Regarding graduate admissions, not having stated deadlines allows a lot more flexibility.  For instance, without these:

- you can admit clear top candidates right away
- you can take more time to discuss borderline/comparable candidates or request more information if needed (often at our meetings we don't get through discussing as many cases as planned, or sometimes want to consult with other faculty not on the committee, or request the applicant submit missing info, etc)
- you can negotiate with the chair/college to admit more people or make better offers to outstanding candidates
- you can make offers right away to other candidates after getting turned down
- you don't want to make candidates think they didn't make the cut, when you think there's a good chance you will make them an offer later but don't currently have the slots
- even though admissions are decided at the department level, you may need approval from the grad college before making actual offers, which may take an unknown amount of extra time

Comment: It's hard to overstate how difficult it is to find suitable common meeting times for a group of professors the size of an admissions committee...